# How to convert the Serial out of a Arduino to socket out put(Lan network)

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, lan, arduino-uno

The below sketch have a serial output at the end of the sketch.
"(Serial.println(stringTwo);)"
How to convert it to a socket output. I want to read the out using a c# program through lan network.

===========

## Sketch

```
int LED= 2;
int LED3= 3;
int LED4= 4;
int LED5= 5;
int LED6= 6;
int LED7= 7;
int LED8= 8;
int LED9= 9;
int LED10= 10;
int LED11= 11;
int LED12= 12;
char k='F';
char a='F';
char b='F';
char c='F';
char d='F';
char e='F';
char f='F';
char g='F';
char h='F';
char i='F';
char j='F';


char data;
char x='f';

char con[80];
int analogpin=3;
void setup() {
  {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED4,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED5,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED6,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED7,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED8,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED9,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED10,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED11,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED12,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(analogpin,INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }

}

void loop() {
  ////////////////
   int value = analogRead(analogpin);
   String stringOne =String(value);

  ////////////////////////////////
 data= Serial.read();

////////////////////////////

  if (data == 'o')
    {
     k='O';
    }
    else if (data == 'p')
      {
       k= 'F';
      }
      else if (data == ' ')
      {
        k= 'F';
      }

       if  (data=='o')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    x = data;
    }
    else if (data=='p')
    {
      digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
      x = data;
      }

///////////////////////////////////
/*if (data !='o'||data !='p')
  {
    data=x;
    }*/
//////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////

if  (data=='A')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED3,HIGH);
    a = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='a')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED3,LOW);
    a  = 'F';
    }
////////////////////////////

    if  (data=='B')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED4,HIGH);
    b = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='b')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED4,LOW);
    b = 'F';
    }

/////////////////////////////

    if  (data=='C')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED5,HIGH);
    c = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='c')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED5,LOW);
    c = 'F';
    }

///////////////////////

    if  (data=='D')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED6,HIGH);
    d = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='d')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED6,LOW);
    d = 'F';
    }
 ///////////////////////

    if  (data=='E')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED7,HIGH);
    e = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='e')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED7,LOW);
    e = 'F';
    }
 /////////////////////

    if  (data=='F')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED8,HIGH);
    f = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='f')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED8,LOW);
    f = 'F';
    }
    ////////////////

    if  (data=='G')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED9,HIGH);
    g = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='g')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED9,LOW);
    g = 'F';
    }
    ////////////

    if  (data=='H')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED10,HIGH);
    h = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='h')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED10,LOW);
    h = 'F';
    }
    ///////////

    if  (data=='I')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED11,HIGH);
    i = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='i')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED11,LOW);
    i = 'F';
    }
    //////////////

    if  (data=='J')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED12,HIGH);
    j = 'O';
   }
  else if (data=='j')
    {
    digitalWrite(LED12,LOW);
    j = 'F';
    }

 String sco(k);
String scoa(a);
String scob(b);
String scoc(c);
String scod(d);
String scoe(e);
String scof(f);
String scog(g);
String scoh(h);
String scoi(i);
String scoj(j);


String stringTwo= sco;
String string3=scoa;
String string4=scob;
String string5=scoc;
String string6=scod;
String string7=scoe;
String string8=scof;
String string9=scog;
String string10=scoh;
String string11=scoi;
String string12=scoj;



     stringTwo.concat(string3);
     stringTwo.concat(string4);
     stringTwo.concat(string5);
     stringTwo.concat(string6);
     stringTwo.concat(string7);
     stringTwo.concat(string8);
     stringTwo.concat(string9);
     stringTwo.concat(string10);
     stringTwo.concat(string11);
     stringTwo.concat(string12);
     stringTwo.concat(stringOne);


      Serial.println(stringTwo);
     delay(100);
}
```

I already developed a  program to read the above sketch out using usb serial port. now i need it through lan network.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",22001))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("string to write");
            }
        }
```

Make sure you a have server running that TcpClient can connect to.
And clean up shop close the client and the writer. Memory issues and open connections. That why the using keyword is used.

This could be the server implementation:

```
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),22001);
        server.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
            {
                while (reader.Read()>0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
```